# Two female beardies in one tank

Tags: bearded-dragon

Me and my sister want to get a bearded dragon, but we want to get two females. Can two females live together in a 120 gallon tank? I'm asking because we are getting them on saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Will it Work?

It is possible with a large tank however bearded dragons are solitary animals and do best by being alone.

### How to Make it Work

- Large terrarium - 120g can work fine
- Multiple Hides in both cool and basking areas
- Multiple basking spots
- Multiple branches for climbing
- Separate feedings - feeding multiple dragons together can end up with one dragon eating the majority of grub while the other one barely gets any. It can also end up in accidental injury from bites.
- Dragons should be the **SAME SIZE ONLY**

If any aggressive behavior is noted they need to be **separated immediately**.

### Conclusion

It is possible but ideally you should buy a separate enclosure for each dragon (55 gal minimum), they get along well as babies but it can change fast once they become adults. Since you are essentially making 2 enclosures in one giant 120g tank you may as well buy 2 separate tanks to be safe.